# MongoEngine Wierdness

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Consider this code:

```
>>> class A(mongoengine.Document):
...     d = mongoengine.DictField()

>>> a = A()
>>> a.d['n'] = 1
>>> a.d['n']
1
```

So far so good. Then:

```
>>> a.d['ns'] = []
>>> a.d['ns']
[]
>>> a.d['ns'].append(a.d['n'])
>>> a.d['ns']
[1]
>>> a.d['ns'].append(a.d['n'])
>>> a.d['ns']
[1]
```

That's weird. Let's try again:

```
>>> a.d['ns'] = [0]
>>> a.d['ns']
[0]
>>> a.d['ns'].append(a.d['n'])
>>> a.d['ns']
[0]
>>> a.d['ns'].append(1)
>>> a.d['ns']
[0, 1]
```

It seems that the problem is in __getitem__ing twice in the same expression; if the list is empty, the item is added; if it's not, nothing happens; but only for __getitem__ed items. What's going on?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm using the latest MongoEngine available at PyPi, namely 0.8.7.

Comment: Precise, what mongoengine version are you using

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a question - bugs are best reported on the github project.

Comment: Post is quite old but for future reference, this bug isn't present anymore (probably since some time)